# Submit web form on a GeckoWebBrowser? (GeckoFX)

Tags: c#, html, .net, vb.net, geckofx

There is a properly way to submit a web form using `GeckoFX` library?

This is what I'm doing to fill a web form and submit the form, but...well, I'm not submitting, I'm just clicking on the last button of the page and I think that can't be the properly way to do it...

Framework's `WebBrowser` control has a method to submit a web form but I can't find any similar method to properly submit a web form on a `GeckWebBrowser`.

```
Dim doc = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document

doc.GetElementById("id_username").
    SetAttribute("value", CStr(MyUsername))

doc.GetElementById("id_password").
    SetAttribute("value", CStr(MyPassword))

doc.GetElementsByTagName("input").
    Last.Click()
```

Comment: have you tried this ? got any exception or error ?

Comment: @xpertgun It works, does not throw any exception... but just I would like to know the properly way to submit a form like in a WebBrowser control with the `WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("Submit")`, this is for generic usage, I can't hardcode the input value/name/tags or something else like in your answer, sorry, I just would like to know if exist something similar for generic use. Thankyou anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GeckoFormElement has a submit method.

So something like this:

```
(GetElementByTagName("form").First() as GeckoFormElement).submit()
```

Comment: Been searching for a couple of hours and this is the first thing that worked! Thanks

Comment: @Tom sorry to arrive late, I don't know how to adapt the code... I'm working with a `GeckoDocument` not a `GeckoFormElement`, anyways I've tried to set a new `GeckoFormElement` but I don't know how to 'cause I can't Cast a `GeckoDocument` to a `GeckoFormElement`... I need a example to use your `submit` method with the code that I've posted in my question, thanks.

Comment: Ok Ive found the right casting by myself: `CType(GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Form").First, GeckoFormElement).Submit()` or this which is the same `GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Form").Cast(Of GeckoFormElement).First.submit()`

Answer (score 3):

I can give example in c# :

If you know id value for input tags and login button , you can do this:

```
 GeckoInputElement username = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Username_ID").DomObject);
 GeckoInputElement Passwd = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd_ID").DomObject);
 GeckoInputElement Loginbutton = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_button_ID").DomObject);
 username.Value = "username";
 Passwd.Value = "password";
 Loginbutton.Click();
```

and if you know `name` of input tags, try this:

```
GeckoInputElement username = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("email")[0].DomObject);
GeckoInputElement password = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByName("pass")[0].DomObject);
GeckoInputElement login = new GeckoInputElement(geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElemntByName("login_name")[0].DomObject);
username.Value = "username";
password.Value = "password";
login.Click();
```

and if you dont know any `id` or `name` of input tags and have class name, try this,

```
GeckoNodeCollection nod = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("classname");
        foreach (GeckoNode node in nod)
        {
            if (NodeType.Element == node.NodeType)
            {

                try
                {
                    GeckoInputElement ele = (GeckoInputElement)node;
                    ele.Click();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string ep = ex.ToString();
                    GeckoHtmlElement ele = (GeckoHtmlElement)no2;
                    ele.Click();
                }                    
            }
        }
```